# How to combine a data frame with another that contains comma separated values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working with 2 data frames that I created based from an Excel file. One data frame contains values that are separated with commas, that is,

```
     df1            df2
-----------      ------------
0   LFTEG42         X,Y,Z
1   JOCOROW         1,2
2   TLR_U01         I
3   PR_UDG5         O,M
```

df1 and df2 are my column names. My intention is to merge the two data frames and generate the following output:

```
 desired result
 ----------
0 LFTEG42X
1 LFTEG42Y
2 LFTEG42Z
3 JOCOROW1
4 JOCOROW2
5 TLR_U01I
6 .....
n PR_UDG5M
```

This is the code that I used but I ended up with the following result:

```
input_file = pd.ExcelFile \
    ('C:\\Users\\devel\\Desktop_12\\Testing\\latest_Calculation' + str(datetime.now()).split(' ')[0] + '.xlsx')

# convert the worksheets to dataframes
df1   = pd.read_excel(input_file, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], parse_cols="H",
                                          sheetname="Analysis")
df2 = pd.read_excel(input_file, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], parse_cols="I",
                                        sheetname="Analysis")

data_frames_merged = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)


current result
--------------
NaN      XYZ
NaN      1,2
NaN      I
...      ...
PR_UDG5  NaN
```

**Questions**

1. Why did I end up receiving a NaN (not a number) value?
2. How can I achieve my desired result of merging these two data frames with the comma values?

Comment: try with `df1 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` instead of append. this is stacking them on top of one an other which is why you have `NaN` values in each column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I break down the steps

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df.df2=df.df2.str.split(',')

df=df.set_index('df1').df2.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1',1).rename(columns={0:'df2'})
df['New']=df.df1+df.df2
df
Out[34]: 
       df1 df2       New
0  LFTEG42   X  LFTEG42X
1  LFTEG42   Y  LFTEG42Y
2  LFTEG42   Z  LFTEG42Z
3  JOCOROW   1  JOCOROW1
4  JOCOROW   2  JOCOROW2
5  TLR_U01   I  TLR_U01I
6  PR_UDG5   O  PR_UDG5O
7  PR_UDG5   M  PR_UDG5M
```

---

Data Input :

```
df1
Out[36]: 
       df1
0  LFTEG42
1  JOCOROW
2  TLR_U01
3  PR_UDG5


df2
Out[37]: 
     df2
0  X,Y,Z
1    1,2
2      I
3    O,M
```

Comment: When I run this line `df.df2 = df.df2.str.split(',')` it throws me the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'df2'`

Comment: I will attach the data input@AlejandroBautistaRamos

Comment: @AlejandroBautistaRamos I am giving the column name as df1 and df2 , you can use yours to replace it , and the code should work

Comment: This is weird, I am not able to run the code. because the `AttributeError` stops me.

Comment: @AlejandroBautistaRamos just using my sample data, if it is work , you need to edit the input of your question

Comment: I had to rename the name of my columns to `df1` and `df2` to make it working. that was the problem with my input. My columns were `Site` and `Sector`.

Comment: @AlejandroBautistaRamos, Yes, it will be much easier if you show the columns' name , Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Dirty one-liner

```
new_df = pd.concat([df1['df1'], df2['df2'].str.split(',', expand = True).stack()\
.reset_index(1,drop = True)], axis = 1).sum(1)


0    LFTEG42X
0    LFTEG42Y
0    LFTEG42Z
1    JOCOROW1
1    JOCOROW2
2    TLR_U01I
3    PR_UDG5O
3    PR_UDG5M
```

Comment: I got this error: `File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5280)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas\_libs\index.c:5126)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1210, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20523)
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1218, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas\_libs\hashtable.c:20477)
KeyError: 0`

Comment: 0 is the column name, are your dataframes df1 and df2 with column names, df1, df2?

Comment: @Vaishali I think the data he provided is not reproducible with his real problem

Comment: @Wen, yeah looks like it. +1 btw

Comment: @Alejandro Bautista Ramos, I edited the code assuming your columns name for df1 is df1 and column name for df2 is df2

Comment: this is the name of my columns and I applied the following: `new_df = pd.concat([df1['Site'], df2['Sector'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack() \
                       .reset_index(1, drop=True)], axis=1).sum(1)` but now I received the `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: Try df1.reset_index(inplace=True) and df2.reset_index(inplace = True) and then go for pd.concat. Should mostly work now

Answer (score 2):

Also, similar to @vaishali except using melt

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2['df2'].str.split(',',expand=True)],axis=1).melt(id_vars='df1').dropna().drop('variable',axis=1).sum(axis=1)

0    LFTEG42X
1    JOCOROW1
2    TLR_U01I
3    PR_UDG5O
4    LFTEG42Y
5    JOCOROW2
7    PR_UDG5M
8    LFTEG42Z
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A='LFTEG42 JOCOROW TLR_U01 PR_UDG5'.split()))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(A='X,Y,Z 1,2 I O,M'.split()))
```

---

Getting creative

```
df1.A.repeat(df2.A.str.count(',') + 1) + ','.join(df2.A).split(',')

0    LFTEG42X
0    LFTEG42Y
0    LFTEG42Z
1    JOCOROW1
1    JOCOROW2
2    TLR_U01I
3    PR_UDG5O
3    PR_UDG5M
dtype: object
```